# Slowing down IIS/SharePoint HTTP response over time

Tags: c#, .net, performance, sharepoint, httpwebrequest

I've a single threaded C#/.NET crawler which downloads file from a SharePoint server (hosted on a VM). The server has about 345k files and uses default windows NTLM authentication. It used to take about 12-13 hours to download and process entire files. Now, mysteriously, the same process takes about 21-24 hours to complete. I log the download times (every 100 files) in a log file and see a varying times for each batch. Please see below:

```
...
12:04:22.521 Scanned items: 1700, Duration(ms): 15850
12:04:38.028 Scanned items: 1800, Duration(ms): 15506
12:04:54.236 Scanned items: 1900, Duration(ms): 16209
12:05:11.115 Scanned items: 2000, Duration(ms): 16879
...
12:08:02.109 Scanned items: 3000, Duration(ms): 14945
12:08:17.444 Scanned items: 3100, Duration(ms): 15334
...
...
17:10:08.835 Scanned items: 90600, Duration(ms): 33150
17:10:49.208 Scanned items: 90700, Duration(ms): **40373**
17:11:29.363 Scanned items: 90800, Duration(ms): **40155**
17:12:08.098 Scanned items: 90900, Duration(ms): 38735
17:12:46.007 Scanned items: 91000, Duration(ms): 37908
17:13:24.165 Scanned items: 91100, Duration(ms): 38158
17:13:52.292 Scanned items: 91200, Duration(ms): 28127
17:14:17.860 Scanned items: 91300, Duration(ms): 25568
17:14:43.569 Scanned items: 91400, Duration(ms): 25709
...
...
09:36:46.476 Scanned items: 345000, Duration(ms): 18533
09:37:05.680 Scanned items: 345100, Duration(ms): 19203
09:37:23.994 Scanned items: 345200, Duration(ms): 18315
...
```

Initially it used to take about 14-16seconds to download a batch of 100 files. Now I am seeing sometimes it takes up to 40-45 seconds to process the same batch. Files on the SharePoint server are of similar size (~1MB each, MS-word documents).

I have already profiled the application but could not spot any tangible difference (between now and earlier code) in the client (C# crawler) side. I'm using [UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing=true](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.unsafeauthenticatedconnectionsharing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%20UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing) and have already tried different values for [ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.connectionleasetimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) including **-1** (never timeout) and **PreAuthenticate=false** (as true slows down further for NTLM).

I have already eliminated the local disk I/O issues by writing the downloaded files to **System.IO.Null** stream. The **GC behavior** of the application is also good (always < 1 % CPU time), no spikes.

I am clueless what could cause almost 100% degradation of performance and why the batch process timings would vary so much (from 14sec/100 files to sometimes 45sec/100 files)?

Thanks in advance, for any pointers.

-BJ

Comment: Can you post the relevant code you use to download files ? The VM Share RAM/CPU with others ? Network is OK ? You have antivirus on your develop machine ? Firewall ? How Many sharepoint frontend do you have ? Site Collection DB is ok ? How much is big ?

Comment: From what you described it seems the problem lies more on the sharepoint side. Do you have a chance to observe what's happening on the server when your download is slowing down? I would check network throughput and CPU consumption of other processes on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my own answer as it might help someone.

In our case, after eliminating any issues in the client side (crawler) we started investigating the SharePoint (SP) Server. SP and SQL Server DB was co-located on the VM and over time we noticed that SP server will log following error:

> **System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException**: The service
>   '/_vti_bin/client.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during
>   compilation.  The exception message is: Memory gates checking failed
>   because the free memory (1041514496 bytes) is less than 5% of total
>   memory.  As a result, the service will not be available for incoming
>   requests..

Similar issue is discussed in the following [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/001b7783-543f-44ca-9004-55351239dae7/how-to-optimize-memory-usage-in-singleserver-farm-setup) also:

After fixing the SP server configuration, the performance was restored back to (almost) earlier level.

-BJ